# firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default.firestore.collection is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to add test data to firestore.
but the following error happened.
how should I fix it?
It seems not that the firebase object is initialized properly.

'../../config/ireBaseConfig'

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import "firebase/storage"

  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "F_U6fgergrsyoBYrgrgrgrgrgr",
    authDomain: "test.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "stack-flow-1333f",
    storageBucket: "stack-over-1333f.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "12345678",
    appId: "1:450307196367:web:foobarfoobar",
    measurementId: "G-foobarfooboogoo"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.firestore();

export const storage = firebase.storage();
export default firebase;
```

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import firebase from '../../config/FireBaseConfig';

class Stack extends Component {


    handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        firebase.firestore.collection("tests").add({

        });
    }
```

> TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default.firestore.collection is not a function

Comment: does your  ./nodes_modules folder has @firebase and firebase dependencies ?

Comment: It's not clear how your first code snippet is involved with this error.  It doesn't seem to be at all involved with the second.

Comment: Yes, It does.    "firebase": "^8.3.0" is written in package.json.

Comment: The error message hint on the dependency for firestore issing, and indeed you don't appear to be importing it based on what you shared, unless is defined in `'../../config/FireBaseConfig'`, is it? Try adding `import 'firebase/firestore';` to your code and let me know if this fixed the issue.